# _set.all for each item in list

Tags: django, foreign-key-relationship

I have a django app where there are comments for a particular answer. now i want to access comment for each answer and render it to a template.

models.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    comment_text = models.TextField()
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(MyUser,blank=True)
    answer_id = models.ForeignKey(Answer, blank=True)
    comment_timestamp=models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
    question_id = models.ForeignKey(Question, blank=True,null=True)
    anonymous_user=models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True)
```

in views.py

```
answer = question.answer_set.all().order_by('-answer_timestamp')
```

is giving me a list of answer

```
[<Answer: It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the .>, <Answer:It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.>]
```

now i want to access comment for each answer.
answer[0].set_all , answer[1].set_all will not be possible because there can be further many answers .

i have tried

```
{% for comment in ans.comment_set.all %}

{% endfor %}
```

in django template but it is not giving the desired result

any other approach so that comments can be passed in context in views.py

Comment: Can you post the code for your `Comment` and `Answer` models?

Comment: Could you add your view?

Comment: "it is not giving the desired result", what is it giving then? that looks like it should work to me

Comment: by desired result i meant that  i had to use other properties for comment models which could be done only by getting it in the for loop
but those divs shouldnt be placed in the for loop

Comment: another way i tried was 
question = Question.objects.get(question_slug = slug)
answer = question.answer_set.all().order_by('-answer_timestamp')
  
  anslength = len(answer)
  for i in range(anslength):
   commentlist.append(answer[i].comment_set.all())

but then i am not able to access commentlist in template

Comment: Can you please update your question explaining your last two comments? its still unclear to me as to why it didn't work..

Comment: for a comment div i need other comment details also like username and date time . for that i have to include a text box in the for loop which otherwise should appear only once on the page

Answer (score 0):

I know It was years ago.

```
{% for i in ans %}
    Answer = {{ i }} 

    Comments : - 
    {% for c in i.comment_set.all %}
        {{ c }} 
    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```